# access an ftp directory with ftplib python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

i'm trying to access an ftp library using a python script
the address of the library is something like this: ftp://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/

so i used this code from [pythonforbegginers](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/how-to-use-ftp-in-python) :

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.sunet.se', 'anonymous', 'anonymous@sunet.se')
print "File List: "
files = ftp.dir()
print files
```

and i tried to use it to suit my case like this:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/','maklit' ,'maklit@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/')
print ("File List: ")
files = ftp.dir()
print (files)
```

but i get the error :
"for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
"

how do i get it to work? what am i doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: First argument is probably either a hostname or an IP address. Looks like you're passing a weird/invalid URL.

Comment: First try to connect with a ftp client. Many browsers can act as a ftp client, and most OS (including Windows) come with a CLI ftp client.

Comment: first dont do that : ftplib.FTP('ftp.host.com' , 'user', 'pase') dont add user and Pass in ftplib.FTP that is the first error then , for login use ftp.login('user', 'pass') not like you did , third , for send a command , use cmd =  ftp.sendcmd('dir') then print(ftplib.parse257(cmd)) , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the hostname `'ftp.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/'` doesn't make sense. `'ftp.'` indicates it is a host name like 'meta.stackoverflow.com', but then you continue with an IP-address, which has to be just numbers and '.', no characters. This means, your IP-address is interpreted as an hostname, which will not work. Use just the IP-address without `'ftp.'`:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

Then you login via the login methode

```
print(ftp.login("your username", "your password"))
```

Then you should see a message 'login successful'. If there stands something like 'Login authentication failed' you have wrong username and password.

Comment: seems like it fix it, but now i get " raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login or password incorrect!

Comment: i tried a lot of combinations. is see "ftp://maklit@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" when i look at preferences of the dir.. what is maklit? user? password? i tried use it as pass and user.  lets say the name of my windows user is ETC1. what do i put in login?  it tried ftp.login('ETC1', 'maklit') and it did not worked.

Comment: need to say i can enter this ftp dir in explorer just by clicking it twice.

Comment: @Adam I edited. If you can enter the directory by clicking twice, you once logged in? What did you use?